# Chrome or iOS Safari not firing 'beforeinstallprompt' for PWA

Tags: html, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Below is my code I am using to listen for the `beforeinstallprompt` event in a React app. I have taken out a lot of unnecessary code so the below is not my complete example, although the React hook is the same.

On my Android and iOS phone I cannot get this event to fire, and the alert "test beforeinstallprompt" does not appear. It does trigger on Chrome on Windows 10 Desktop however. And on Android, I can install the app from the custom menu bar and then the `alert('appinstalled')` runs which is weird.

So it's confirmed working in Chrome desktop, it is just not triggered on mobile devices. What am I missing?

```js
export default function MyComponent() {
    const [deferredPrompt, setDeferredPrompt] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            setDeferredPrompt(e)
            alert('test beforeinstallprompt')
        })
        window.addEventListener('appinstalled', () => {
            alert('appinstalled')
        })
    }, [])
    return null
}
```